# Writing GMAIL inbox html to file fails (VBA, Textstream)

Tags: vba

I retrieved a HTML file that I want to save using a textstream object from FileSystemObjects and it produces an empty file.

When I use MsgBox to display the stream right before the write command it shows all the HTML code I want, but it doesn't write the code to the file. Any suggestions?

```
Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
Dim FSOFile As TextStream
Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = "C:\myhtml.html"

Set FSO = New FileSystemObject
Set FSOFile = FSO.OpenTextFile(FilePath, 2, True)

   FSOFile.Write myContent ' String object holding the HTML textstring
   FSOFile.Close
```

I basically am trying to export my gmail inbox folder which I want to use as an event listener (so I can tell another machine what it is supposed to do.) .

On your comments so far: 
- riteLine does not make any difference
- OpenTextFile creates non-existing files and it also creates the file and writes any other string that I manually type in, s.a. FSOFile.WriteLine "Nothing works" 
- For completeness: CreateTextFile also did not help.

Any likely problem of writing the HTML code using the FSO  stream?

Comment: people use these technologies which fail for unexplicable reasons, for unexplicable reasons.

Comment: if the file does not exist, you need to use `CreateTextFile` instead of `OpenTextFile`

Answer (score 0):

Try WriteLine instead of just Write.
See Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242706%28v=vs.60%29.aspx